# exponential notation to integer notation XSLT2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

IS it possible to change the following exponential notation to integer notation using XSLT 2.0.

**2.0151109001E10
to
20151109001**

I tried with

```
number(2.0151109001E10)
```

but it gives NaN as answer.

EDIT:
XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="a" select="ss:Cell[$key]/ss:Data"/>
<xsl:variable name="b" select="string($a)"/>
<xsl:variable name="c" select="number($b)"/>
```

OUTPUT:

```
 <a>2.0151109001E10</a>
 <b>2.0151109001E10</b>
 <c>2.0151109001E10</c>
```

**The following works out**

```
<xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal(xs:double(translate($a, ',', '.')))"/>
```

Comment: Where is the number 7,2345E7 coming from?

Comment: @michael - The data is read from Excel xml file using XSLT

Comment: If the given number does not contain a comma - as shown now that you have edited your example - then there is no reason to use `translate()` to convert it to a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem with your input is not the exponential notation, but the use of a comma as the decimal mark. XML only recognizes a period as the decimal  mark.

Try something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal(xs:double(translate($a, ',', '.')))"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate($a, ',', '.'), '0')"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put them inside the single quotes `''` like this:

```
number('7.2345E7')
```

gives

```
72340000
```

Comment: I am doing number(string(7,2345E7)). But this is not working

Comment: @Joe:- Simply do: `number('7.2345E7')`

Comment: I eloborated my question further

Answer (score 0):

You can use format-number:

```
format-number(2.0151109001E10, '#')
```